# How to set up a model for two independent sets of data?

Tags: likelihood

[image][image]If we have two groups of data:

Group 0: Subjects $n_0$, Events $k_0$, Parameters $p_0$

Group 1: Subjects $n_1$, Events $k_1$, Parameters $p_1$,

and we need to propose a model for the data in terms of two random variables which we should define.

I am not sure how to define these variables. Should I just write variables $V_0$ and $V_1$ belongs to the normal distribution? And then, how should I write joint log likelihood for $p_0$, $p_1$? Is that some general expression? Would this setting mean that probability $P(V_0=k_0)=p_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are testing the null hypothesis $H_0: p_0 = p_1$ that two
binomial processes have the same Success probability against the two-sided
alternative $H_a: p_0 \ne p_1$ that the Success probabilities differ.

While this is a problem about binomial random variables $X_0 \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n_0, p_0)$ and $X_1 \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n_1, p_1),$ perhaps the most frequently used test
uses [a normal
approximation](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm), when $n_1$ and $n_2$ are sufficiently large. The estimates are $\hat p_0 = X_0/n_0$ and $\hat p_1 = X_1/n_1.$

Under the null hypothesis that $p_0 = p_1 = p,$ one can estimate $p$ by
$\hat p = \frac{X_1+X_2}{N_1 + n_2}.$ Then the test statistic is
$$Z = \frac{\hat p_0 - \hat p_1}{\mathrm{SD}(\hat p_0 -\hat p_1)} \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$$
where $\mathrm{SD}(\hat p_0 - \hat p_1) = 
\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)(1/n_0 + 1/n_1)}.$

Because you have shown no work towards a solution, I have no way of knowing
whether this is the formulation of the problem envisioned by your textbook,
but it is a frequently used one.

For the hypothetical data shown, here is an implementation of this approximate
normal test from a recent release of Minitab:

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample    X    N  Sample p
1       103  150  0.686667
2       224  275  0.814545

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.127879
95% CI for difference:  (-0.215173, -0.0405848)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
  Z = -2.99  P-Value = 0.003

Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 0.004
```

At the end, note the result of [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test), which is based on
a hypergeometric distribution.

Various versions of this test have been implemented in different software
packages. Some use individual estimates of $p_0$ and $p_1$ and some (as in Minitab above) estimate the common proportion $p.$ Some use continuity corrections and some don't. So P-values may differ somewhat from one implementation to another.

Below are results of two versions a similar test from `prob.test` in R
(with and without continuity correction). The chi-squared statistic shown is the square of standard normal Z:

```
prop.test(c(103,224), c(150,275))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
               with continuity correction

data:  c(103, 224) out of c(150, 275)
X-squared = 8.2399, df = 1, p-value = 0.004098
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.22032428 -0.03543329
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.6866667 0.8145455 

prop.test(c(103,224), c(150,275), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
              without continuity correction

data:  c(103, 224) out of c(150, 275)
X-squared = 8.9461, df = 1, p-value = 0.002781
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.21517277 -0.04058481
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.6866667 0.8145455
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain how to form log likelihood ? And should $k_0$ and $k_1$ be in the formulas you gave? Are they important?

Comment: If this is a textbook problem which explicitly asks for a log likelihood approach you will have to decide whether to start with the exact binomial distributions or with approximate normal ones. Maybe the placement of the problem in the book gives a clue. What topics and methods are discussed just before the problem appears. Are there any examples nearby using likelihood ratios for discrete distributions?

Comment: I've added the precise question as image attachment. Hope this helps, this is the only thing I have.

Comment: First review rules for MLEs and uses of log odds ratios. Then solution should go something like: (a) $X_0\sim\mathsf{Binom}(n_0,\pi_0);$ similarly for $X_1.$ (b) MLE of $\pi_0$ is $\hat\pi_0=X_0/n_0;$ similarly for MLE of $\pi_1.$ (c) MLE for $\delta =\pi_0-\pi_1$ is $\hat\delta=\hat\pi_0-\hat\pi_1.$ Also, log odds ratio will indicate rejection for $\hat \delta$ too large or too small. Finally, use normal aprx to find critical values. // Suggest you edit your Q to show progress, asking for help if you get totally stuck along the way.

Comment: I've added my trial. I am not sure if that is correct, and I do not know how to solve part c.